# UITableView don't reuse cells, good case to do this?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iso

I have 5 cells in a UITableView.  Each has a UITextField as a subview, where the user will input data.  If I DO use cell reuse, the textfield gets cleared if the cells are scrolled out of view.  I don't want to have to deal with this.  Is there a way to NOT reuse cells so that I don't have this issue, if so, how?

Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Your choice to reuse or not won't stop the iOS from removing cells from the table and potentially releasing them. Maybe the iOS won't remove a cell as long as it has/is the first responder (e.g. While editing the text field)

Comment: Kris - This is good to know.  So, I really need to store my users input into an array or something so that I can put it back into the textfield when the cell scrolls back in...

Comment: That would definitely be safer. It could be that you can avoid an unload just by retaining your own cellviews, e.g. In an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same feature in one of my apps and I used below code to accomplish that and I never had this kind of problem.

First of all you need to store all your textField value temporary in Array. Make array like this.

```
arrTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],nil];
```

Then Give all textField tag = indexPath.row;

After that You need to replace textField value in below two methods.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
   [arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
}
```

At Last You need to set that value in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource Method. So that whenever user scroll tableview it set previous value from temp array. Like this.

```
cell.txtEntry.text = [arrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It might possible I forgot some of the code to paste here. So if you have any problem please let me know.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` is very curious. If your goal is to get an empty `NSString`, Why wouldn't you just use `@""` directly, or `[NSString string]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can give each cell a unique ReuseIdentifier, maybe by appending the indexPath.row to the name. If you have only 5 cells, this will probably be fine, but you're losing one of the main benefits of a `UITableView`. In this case, you may want to use a `UIScrollView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 5 textview's is a perfect case for not queueing and de-queueing the cells, just create them all in view did load, store in an array and return as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up [Apple's Recipes sample application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iphonecoredatarecipes/Introduction/Intro.html), you will see how Apple uses a xib file to load UITableViewCells.

In the IngredientDetailViewController file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet EditingTableViewCell *editingTableViewCell;
// ...
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EditingTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
// this will cause the IBOutlet to be connected, and you can now use self.editingTableViewCell
```

Although it looks like they are reusing the cell, you could use the same method to load the 5 cells into 5 separate IBOutlets, and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you just return those 5 rather than calling the dequeue method.

Note: you will probably need to store the cells as `strong` properties (rather than `assign`ing them).