# Don't reuse cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

I don't want to reuse the cells once the cell is created,
I want it to be available in memory.

Comment: what issue you are faced ?

Comment: I don't want to reuse cell if i views in a stack view which is added to the cell. On show hide of those subviews the constraints get affected and UI gets disturbed.

Comment: So i want to keep the cells in memory. @KKRocks

Comment: Fix your cell's autolayout instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView don't reuse cells, good case to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516065/uitableview-dont-reuse-cells-good-case-to-do-this)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's your decision of course, but it's a ***very bad*** idea. Unless you have less than 10 cells in your `tableView` and you are 100% sure there will be no more cells. Otherwise the app will crash on memory pressure pretty fast.

Just don't `dequeue` cells. Create new each time:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier")
```

Not recommended, but it's your decision after all.

---

> A note about most recent swift versions:
>
> '***`UITableViewCellStyle`***' has been renamed to '***`UITableViewCell.CellStyle`***'

Comment: I have a custom cell class. Cannot use the above code.

Comment: @MukulMore then: `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableViewCell`

Comment: `let cell = YourCustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "YourCustomCellReuseIdentifier") as! YourCustomTableViewCell`

Comment: the above method always returns the nil object

Comment: less than 10 cells? Seriously? You can probably have 1000 cells without performance issues. Have you a ever played a game on your device?

Comment: @Vignesh same problem. any updates?

Answer (score 2):

If you have limited number of cell then only you should use this method:

On `viewDidLoad()` you can create NSArray of custom cell

```
self.arrMainCell.addObject(your custom cell);

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.arrMain.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.arrMain.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a tableview. Just use a scrollview. Use tableview if you have a long list where you can't keep all the views in memory.

Answer (score -1):

When you need a cell object at runtime, call the table view’s dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) method, passing the reuse identifier for the cell you want.
**The table view maintains an internal queue of already-created cells.**

If the queue contains a cell of the requested type, the table view returns that cell.
If not, it creates a new cell using the prototype cell in your storyboard. Reusing cells improves performance by minimizing memory allocations during critical times, such as during scrolling.

If you change the appearance of your custom cell’s views,
implement the prepareForReuse() method of your cell subclass.
In your implementation, return the appearance of your cell's views to their original state.
For example, if you change the alpha property of a view in your cell, return that property to its original value