# How to stop webview reload located on tabview cell while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uiwebview

I have webview in table view cell , whenever tableview cell is scrolling ,Web view reloads ....How to stop webview reload while tableview is scrolling.

Comment: As per my suggestion, you need to replace webview with UItextview and load your HTML Content as an attributed string in UItextview because webview is reloading every time while scrolling and display table view cell. it takes to much time to load and disturb scrolling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't reuse cell in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487865/dont-reuse-cell-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Hi iOSDev please follow the following link

[Don't reuse cell in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487865/dont-reuse-cell-in-uitableview)

Max Pevsner solution fulfills your problem of not dequeuing the cell with just instantiating a table view cell.

But my suggestion is you use static webView, instead of not dequeuing the cell, as it will always stay in memory till the tableview is loaded, and moreover every time the cell will be created again when you will scroll the tableview. not dequeuing cell will be least efficient, for the tableview.